# C# - IronPython, running 3rd party python package

Tags: c#, python-3.x, ironpython

I am trying to run a python script via a C# project, so far I have downloaded the IronPython & IronPython StdLib nuget packages and manually downloaded the src files for the 3rd party python module into the IronPython 'site-packages' folder.

Installed c# packages:

- IronPython 3.4.1
- IronPython.StdLib 3.4.1

Python modules:

- pynput

My directory inside visual studios:

[image]

What i've tried:

- Added search path for the engine to the site-packages folder (different variations)

```
  ICollection<string> paths = _engine.GetSearchPaths();
  paths.Add(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\lib\site-packages\");
  _engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
```

- Append to sys.paths in python script

Python script:

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

mouse = Controller()

# Read pointer position
print('The current pointer position is {0}'.format(mouse.position))
```

When I run the above python code via IronPython, I get an ImportException.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?